# Getting spfx test result into VSTS

Tags: spfx-tooling

I try to get my Unit Test from the spfx test into VSTS. A `gulp test` creates in the `temp` folder a `result.json`. But I found no documentation which file format is this file has?

Trying JUnit format did not work for me. Can I get spfx to produce a test result file that VSTS understands or VSTS to read the format spfx produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution in https://github.com/baywet/spfx-devops-vsts

1. Install `karma-junit-reporter` with `npm i karma-junit-reporter -D`
2. Add to `gulpfile.js`

   ```
   // Extending Karma
   const karmaTask = build.karma;
   if (karmaTask) {
     karmaTask.taskConfig.configPath = './config/karma.config.js';
   }
   ```
3. Create a `./conig/karma.config.js` with

   ```
   "use strict";
   var existingKarmaConfig = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web/lib/karma/karma.config');
   var junitReporter = require('karma-junit-reporter');
   // based on https://github.com/baywet/spfx-devops-vsts/blob/master/config/karma.config.js
   module.exports = function (config) {
     existingKarmaConfig(config);
     config.reporters.push('junit');
     config.junitReporter = {
       outputDir: 'temp/', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
       outputFile: 'test-results.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
       suite: 'karma', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
       useBrowserName: true, // add browser name to report and classes names
     };
     config.plugins.push(junitReporter);
   };
   ```
4. In VSTS gulp test Task enable `Publish to TFS/Team Services` in the `JUnit Test Results` section and change to `Test Results Files` to `**/test-*.xml`
   [image: VSTS gulp test settings]